# How to EXACTLY save the state of a program in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, serialization

Im making a small gui application where it takes words from a text file converted into python list, displays it, provides yes/no buttons and upon clicking shows the next random word and removes the previously shown word from that list. The problem is how can i make sure that after a few clicks if i want to close the application it knows where i left off and starts from there the next time i open it again instead of going back to its original state where no words have been removed from the list. In other words, how EXACTLY do i save the current state of my running program so that i can resume it later on?

I searched around and found out about serialization, which `Pickle` & `JSON` do, but they dont really make sense to me and i also don't understand how to implement them here.

**The code:**

```
from random import randint
from tkinter import *

dictionary=[]
with open('Dictionary.txt', 'r') as words:
    dictionary = [word.split('\n')[0] for word in words]


root= Tk()
root.title('')
root.geometry('300x500')

#progress = 0

def yes_():
    #select a random number
    n = randint(0,len(dictionary))
    
    #pass to list and print word on label
    global l
    l.grid_forget()
    l = Label(root, text = dictionary[n])
    l.config(font=('Arial', 25))
    l.grid(row=0, padx=100, pady=100)

    #remove that word
    dictionary.remove(dictionary[n])
    #progress += 1

def no_():
    global l
    l.grid_forget()
    l = Label(root, text='test click')
    l.config(font=('Arial', 25))
    l.grid(row=0, padx=100, pady=100)

l = Label(root, text='Hello')
l.config(font=('Arial', 30))
l.grid(row=0, padx=100, pady=100)


question = Label(root, text='Do you know this word?', anchor='center')
question.config(font=('Arial', 12))
question.grid(row=1, pady=20)

by = Button(root, text='Yes', command=yes_)
by.config(font=('Arial', 15))
by.grid(row=2, ipadx=20)

bn = Button(root, text='No', command=no_)
bn.config(font=('Arial', 15))
bn.grid(row=3, pady=10, ipadx=26)

root.mainloop()
```

**Edit1:**
ok, so after suggestions of @fernandezr and @Cool i did some searching and i was able to save the changed list `dictionary` into a pickle. ( i did'nt get what @acw1668 & @Tkinter were sayying, sorry guys) but now how do i make it load back such that when i open the program again it resumes from there?

**code bit:**

```
def on_close():
    with open(r'C:\Users\Tos\Documents\t.pickle', 'wb') as text:
        pickle.dump(dictionary, text)
    root.destroy()

...

root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_close)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried to capture the close event from the window and then write the settings to a serialized file?

Comment: Use `root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',func)` and inside `func`, save the words to a file, which will be read from when the game starts again.

Comment: Simple way is saving current content of `dictionary` back to `Dictionary.txt` after the line `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: store all the events in a txt file, then when starting the app, use the txt file to save the previous version...

Comment: Since you have read `Dictionary.txt` into `dictionary` when program starts, you can simply save `dictionary` back to `Dictionary.txt` after `root.mainloop()`: `with open("Dictionary.txt", "w") as words: words.write("\n".join(dictionary))`.

Comment: @acw1668 but if i do that then wouldn't that just copy paste words in the file all over again? and i dont want to change the original .txt file because my program references words from it and only removes them from the list object of python, not the .txt file. Anyway the problem of saving has been solved but now i need to be able to load it, if you can suggest something i appreciate it.

Comment: Then you need to load the pickle file (if you use pickle file for saving the dictionary) at the program starts like you load `Dictionary.txt`.  If there is no pickle file, then load the `Dictionary.txt` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for my specific situation i found a solution. In my question i made an edit that i found how to save the program, to be exact i was able to make a saving mechanism that works . And for the loading mechanism i just had to load that saved file(as suggested by @acw1668) and assign it to the variable `dictionary`, this replaces the original list made from the `.txt` file to the altered list from the `pickle`d file.

**The entire code:**

```
from random import randint
from tkinter import *
import pickle

dictionary=[]
with open('Dictionary.txt', 'r') as words:
    dictionary = [word.split('\n')[0] for word in words]

root= Tk()
root.title('')
root.geometry('300x500')

def on_close():
    with open(r'C:\Users\Tos\Documents\t.pickle', 'wb') as t_pickle:
        pickle.dump(dictionary, t_pickle)
    root.destroy()

def yes_():
    n = randint(0,len(dictionary))
    global text_label
    text_label.grid_forget()
    text_label = Label(root, text = dictionary[n])
    text_label.config(font=('Arial', 25))
    text_label.grid(row=0, padx=100, pady=100)
    dictionary.remove(dictionary[n])

def no_():
    global text_label
    text_label.grid_forget()
    text_label = Label(root, text='test click')
    text_label.config(font=('Arial', 25))
    text_label.grid(row=0, padx=100, pady=100)

try:
    with open(r'C:\Users\Tos\Documents\t.pickle', 'rb') as t_pickle:
        dictionary = pickle.load(t_pickle)
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

text_label = Label(root, text='Hello')
text_label.config(font=('Arial', 30))
text_label.grid(row=0, padx=100, pady=100)

question = Label(root, text='Do you know this word?', anchor='center')
question.config(font=('Arial', 12))
question.grid(row=1, pady=20)

by = Button(root, text='Yes', command=yes_)
by.config(font=('Arial', 15))
by.grid(row=2, ipadx=20)

bn = Button(root, text='No', command=no_)
bn.config(font=('Arial', 15))
bn.grid(row=3, pady=10, ipadx=26)

root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_close)
root.mainloop()
```

If you would like to know why i used `try..except` block then the reason is the first time user opens program there wont be any save file available, so to let the error pass easily. this also works for the part when the program is saved upon exiting the file is created and so the continuation of progress can be done.

Finally i would like to say that although i got what i wanted, i feel that this is a work around. i was expecting python to have some function or something that implements save/load functionality; Maybe it does and i dont know about it, im no expert at python. Its possible i worded the question incorrectly. im still interested in knowing how to pause/save the state of a running program, i found many stackeroverflow users asking the same thing and not getting an expected answer. if anyone does know that there exxists a save/load/pause functionality for running programs in python plz do link it.